# How to correctly implement triple buffering?

Tags: multithreading, synchronization, producer-consumer, lock-free, buffering

I am trying to simulate videocard (producer thread) and a monitor(consumer thread), to figure out what is going on in educational purposes. So here is the technical task
description:

Producer thread produces frames pixel data at 1000 fps. Consumer thread runs at 60 fps and every frame it must have access to last produced frame for at least 1/60th of second. Each frame is represented by some `int*`, for simplicity.

So my solution is that i have array of 2 pointers: one for producer, one for consumer. And plus some free, unused pointer, which is not owned by consumer or producer at any given moment of time.

```
#define Producer 0
#define Consumer 1
int* usedPointers[2];
std::atomic<int*> freePointer;
```

- producer always writes frame pixels to `usedPointers[Producer]`, then does `usedPointers[Producer] = freePointer.exchange(usedPointers[Producer], memorySemanticsProducer);` so that last completely produced frame is now pointed by `freePointer`, and its free to write new frame, not destroying last actual complete frame.
- consumer does `usedPointers[Consumer] = freePointer.exchange(usedPointers[Consumer], memorySemanticsConsumer);` so that it would own last actual frame data, and then is free to access `usedPointers[Consumer]` as long, as it desires to.

Correct me if i am wrong.

I miss what is `memorySemanticsXXX`. [There are descriptions](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/atomic/memory_order/) but i cannot figure out which exactly should i use in every thread and why. So i am asking for some hints on that.

Comment: Aren't you missing one more buffer here, though? What if consumer uses usedPointers[1] (i.e. displaying its content) while producer swaps the buffers twice? (i.e. first writing into usedPointers[0], then into usedPointers[1]) For proper triple buffering you need, well, three buffers: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_buffering#Triple_buffering

Comment: @MiroKropacek No I am not missing, seeing all 3 pointers in 2 variables. Here is exactly 3 buffers. 2 currently acquired buffers are represented by `int*` pointers of `usedPointers`, and third, unused buffer - is represented by `atomic int*` pointer `freePointer`, which is the exactly the pointer that is concurrently being modified with exhange op, that way - shared by both `Producer` and `Consumer` threads. So Triple buffering is yeah, 3 buffers, you're right. Do you still miss third? Wikipedia article wont help here, a bit irrelevant..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`memorySemanticsXXX` you're mentioning are about the rest of your code surrounding the `exchange()` lines. The default behavior for `std::atomic::exchange()` is that `memory_order_seq_cst` is used (the second parameter for `exchange()` you're not using).

This means three things at the same time:

- Any code you wrote before your `exchange()` call is guaranteed to execute before that call (otherwise compiler optimizations can reorder your code) **and** the results of that execution will be visible in all other threads (CPU cache propagation) before the `exchange()` call is made.
- The same as previous but for the code you wrote after your `exchange()` line.
- All of the code before and after `exchange()` call is executed in the exact order you wrote it (including other atomic operations).

So, the whole point is that you may choose not to have one, two or all three of these restrictions, which *can* bring you speed improvements. You shouldn't bother with this **unless you have a performance bottleneck**. If there's no bottleneck then just use `std::atomic` without the second parameter (it will take the default value).

In case you don't use all three restrictions you have to be really careful writing your code otherwise it can unpredictably crash.

Read more about it here: [Memory order](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/memory_order)

Comment: I've got it, that at current frequencies i would not expect any performance gains. But i wonder, what if that `exchange()` is the last statement in the producer thread loop (and must just execute last and be atomic), and is a first statement in a consumer thread loop(must just execute first there and be atomic)? There are no other atomics and rest of the code could be reordered. Can i use relaxed atomics then and which?

Comment: I don't think you will gain anything if the atomic operation is first or last and you use more relaxed memory ordering. For example, if it's the last, the compiler might improve performance only if reordering something to execute after it, which is not allowed and you gain nothing. The more serious issue is the CPU cache. On Intel CPUs it's not much important if two threads are executing on the same physical CPU. But if two threads are executing on different CPUs compiler generates the code to flush the cache to RAM in order for other thread to see the changes, if memory order is strict.

Comment: Actually, on second thought, you **can** use `memory_order_acquire` on atomic operation at the beginning and `memory_order_release` on atomic operation at the end. This will still allow compiler to reorganize and optimize code between these two operations but cache flushes will still happen before first and second atomic operation. Since you're using the buffer between these two calls this is maybe the best you can do.

Comment: But, remember, go that way **only if and when you need to optimize for performance** and you identified exactly these operations as offenders, not before.

Comment: Acquire is for loading operations and release for storing, but `exchange()` is read-modify-write operation. Are you sure i can go with just acqiore and just release semantics, but not both in either cases?

Comment: Release guarantees that all the changes a thread done before calling it's `exchange()` at the end will be visible after the first `exchange()` in the other thread. Acquire is just the other way around. It does not have anything to do with what kind of operation is `exchange()`.
You're just telling the compiler that any code after the first `exchange()` call must see the up to date values changed by other threads, not the old values from cache and all of the code before `exchange()` is executed (not reordered to execute later).

Comment: Imagine one process doing a buffered write into a log file and another one reading from it. The writer can do a write call and don't care if this was actually flushed to file. The reader will then see nothing or only partial content. This is a case like relaxed memory ordering.
If you flush the buffer in writer after every log entry output, this is like `release` operation. Reader will always see the complete output. `acquire` is the same flush but initiated by reader.

Comment: Well, the description is not 100% accurate but I hope you get the principle. The best thing you can do and be completely sure is to play with the settings and look at the disassembly. Look for instructions like: [MFENCE](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/MFENCE.html), [CLFLUSH](https://c9x.me/x86/html/file_module_x86_id_30.html), [CMPXCHG](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/CMPXCHG.html), etc.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a perfect answer that I would answer myself back then, if I could have time machine:

The choice of memory order depends on your specific use case and requirements. You should use the weakest memory order, that still ensures correctness and consistency of your algorithm. Typical choices include:

- You should use `std::memory_order_seq_cst` if you want to avoid any surprises or complications, but you may pay a performance penalty for it.
- You should use `std::memory_order_relaxed` if you don’t care about ordering or synchronization at all, but you may introduce subtle bugs or race conditions if you do.
- You should use `std::memory_order_acquire` and `std::memory_order_release` if you want to implement a producer-consumer pattern, where one thread writes data and releases it, and another thread reads data and acquires it.
- You should use `std::memory_order_acq_rel` if you want to implement a read-modify-write operation, where one thread reads data, modifies it, and writes it back atomically.

Based on your exact description, it seems, that you want to implement a producer-consumer pattern, where the producer thread writes frame pixels to a buffer and the consumer thread reads them. You also want to avoid performance penalty by using weaker memory orders than sequential consistency. In that case, you can use `std::memory_order_release` for `memorySemanticsProducer` and `std::memory_order_acquire` for `memorySemanticsConsumer`. This way, you ensure that the producer thread does not write to the buffer before releasing the pointer, and that the consumer thread does not read from the buffer after acquiring the pointer. This also prevents any reordering of memory accesses around the exchange operation that could cause inconsistency or data races.

Here is a possible demo snippet of your code using these memory orders:

```
#define Producer 0
#define Consumer 1
int* usedPointers[2];
std::atomic<int*> freePointer;

void threadProducer() {
  while(true) {
    // write frame pixels to usedPointers[Producer]
    // ...
    // release the pointer and exchange it with freePointer
    usedPointers[Producer] = freePointer.exchange(usedPointers[Producer], std::memory_order_release);
  }
}

void threadConsumer() {
  while(true) {
    // acquire the pointer and exchange it with freePointer
    usedPointers[Consumer] = freePointer.exchange(usedPointers[Consumer], std::memory_order_acquire);
    // read frame pixels from usedPointers[Consumer]
    // ...
  }
}

int main() {
  // initialize usedPointers and freePointer
  usedPointers[Procuder] = init_buf();
  usedPointers[Consumer] = init_buf();
  freePointer.Store(init_buf());
  // create producer and consumer threads
  std::thread t1(threadProducer);
  std::thread t2(threadConsumer);
  // join threads
  t1.join();
  t2.join();
  return 0;
}
```

moreover, instead of using global array of pointers - it *may be* better (may be easier for compiler/caching mechanisms, may be not) to define producer and consumer local buffer variable right inside corresponding thread functions themselves, but that may make buffer init code abit less beautiful - more scattered accross functions. Thich may be unwanted, if you plan to place functions across different files:

```
void threadConsumer() {
  auto buffer = init_buf();
  while(true) {
    // acquire the consumer buffer pointer and exchange it with freePointer
    buffer = freePointer.exchange(buffer, std::memory_order_acquire);
    ...
```

That will led you to better understanding, that triple buffer global state - consists of only one atomic pointer, which is shared buffer and a mechanism that is aware how to init it - two buffers may be fully thread-local

Comment: But how would you know if there is actually new data available? Or does this depend on the producer being faster?

Comment: @veio usecase was simulation and rendering. simulation(producer) was producing at 1000 fps, while rendering(consumer) was rendering 60 fps. (or 120, or 144 depending on gpu and monitor), but i think you've got the idea