# Why does this SDL2 program slow down?

Tags: c, sdl

I have a problem with this program that reads audio data from an input device and displays a line representing the volume level. It starts ok then a few seconds later it starts lagging. It worked without slow downs until I tried to add some code to add image display functionality, which didn't work so I removed it, but now it the program doesn't work properly. I've removed most of the program functionality which I'll add back if I fix it. The CPU and GPU usage remains low so no problems there. If I switch to Software Mode it seems to work. I'm on Windows using MinGW-w64.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>
#include <math.h>

int SCREEN_WIDTH = 1024; //default
int SCREEN_HEIGHT = 768; //default
int FULLSCREEN = 0;

SDL_Renderer *rend;

//#define SOFTWARE_RENDER
//#define VSYNC_ON

#define PROGRAM_NAME "My Game"
#ifdef SOFTWARE_RENDER
#define RENDERER SDL_RENDERER_SOFTWARE
#else
#define RENDERER SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED
#endif

#if !defined(SOFTWARE_RENDER) && defined(VSYNC_ON)
#define VSYNC SDL_RENDERER_PRESENTVSYNC
#else
#define VSYNC 0
#endif


////https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_AudioSpec#callback
void audioInCallback(void *userdata, Uint8 *stream,int len)
{
    float *floatStream = (float*)stream;

    if (stream == NULL)
    {
        puts("Stream is NULL.");
        return;
    }
    SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(rend, 0, 0, 0, 255);
    SDL_RenderClear(rend);
    SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(rend, 255, 255, 255, 255);

    float avg = 0;

    for (int i=0;i<len;i++)
        avg += fabs(floatStream[i]);

    avg /= len;

    SDL_RenderDrawLine(rend, 0,
                               SCREEN_HEIGHT/2 + round(SCREEN_HEIGHT/2.0 * avg),
                               SCREEN_WIDTH,
                               SCREEN_HEIGHT/2 + round(SCREEN_HEIGHT/2.0 * avg)
                               );

    return;
}

int main(int argv, char *argc[])
{
    int bufferSize = 8;
    SDL_Window* window = NULL;
    rend = NULL;
    SDL_Event event;
    bool loopIsActive = true;
    SDL_AudioSpec want, have;
    SDL_AudioDeviceID dev;


    if (SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO | SDL_INIT_AUDIO) != 0)
    {
        printf("Unable to initialize SDL: %s", SDL_GetError());
        return 1;
    }

    if( (window = SDL_CreateWindow( PROGRAM_NAME, SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED,
                                    SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, SCREEN_WIDTH,
                                    SCREEN_HEIGHT, SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN )) == NULL )
    {
        printf("Window could not be created! %s\n", SDL_GetError());
        SDL_Quit();
        return 0;
    }

    if ( (rend = SDL_CreateRenderer(window, -1, RENDERER | VSYNC)) == NULL )
    {
        printf("Error creating renderer. %s\n", SDL_GetError());
        SDL_DestroyWindow(window);
        SDL_Quit();
        return 0;
    }
    int count = SDL_GetNumAudioDevices(1);

    for (int i=0;i<count;i++)
    {
        printf("%d. %s\n", i, SDL_GetAudioDeviceName(i, 1));
    }

    SDL_memset(&want, 0, sizeof(want)); /* or SDL_zero(want) */
    want.freq = 44100;
    want.format = AUDIO_S16;
    want.channels = 1;
    want.samples = pow(2,bufferSize);
    want.callback = audioInCallback;

    dev = SDL_OpenAudioDevice(NULL, 1, &want, &have, SDL_AUDIO_ALLOW_FORMAT_CHANGE);


    if (dev == 0)
        printf("Failed to open audio: %s", SDL_GetError());
    else
    {
        printf("have.samples = %u\n", have.samples);
        printf("Opened device %s\nAudio format: ", SDL_GetAudioDeviceName(0, 1));
        if (SDL_AUDIO_ISFLOAT(have.format))
            printf("%d-bit %s\n", SDL_AUDIO_BITSIZE(have.format), SDL_AUDIO_ISFLOAT(have.format) ? "float" :
                                                                  SDL_AUDIO_ISSIGNED(have.format) ? "signed" : "unsigned");
        SDL_PauseAudioDevice(dev, 0); /* start audio playing. */
    }

    while (loopIsActive == true)
    {
        while (SDL_PollEvent(&event))
        {
            switch (event.type)
            {
                case SDL_QUIT:
                    loopIsActive = false;
                    break;
                case SDL_KEYDOWN:
                    if (event.key.keysym.scancode == SDL_SCANCODE_ESCAPE)
                    {
                        loopIsActive = false;
                    }
                    break;
            }
        }

        SDL_RenderPresent(rend);
        SDL_Delay(16);
    }


    if (dev != 0) SDL_CloseAudioDevice(dev);
    SDL_DestroyRenderer(rend);
    SDL_DestroyWindow(window);
    SDL_Quit();

    puts("Hello world!");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Audio callback runs in separate thread and SDL graphics can only be used in thread that initialised graphics/created window. Audio callback seems wrong for that case because you have no control over `len` so your average gets updated only once per buffer, not per frame; if that's what you wanted I would recommend updating average in callback but rendering unconditionally in main loop.

Comment: OT: regarding the `switch()` statement and associated `case` statements:  older C implementations would crash if none of the `case` statements matched the value passed to `switch()`.  To be safe, suggest include a `default:` case (which probably contains nothing but the `break;` statement

Comment: OT: regarding; `bool loopIsActive = true;` and `while (loopIsActive == true)` and `loopIsActive = false;`  In C, any value other than 0 evaluates to `true`.  Therefore, suggest:  `int loopIsActive = 1;` and `while ( loopIsActive )` and `loopIsActive = 0;`

Comment: have you checked to display how long this loop: `while (SDL_PollEvent(&event))` is activated?  Suggest just using: `if( SDL_PollEvent(&event) )` so only handle a single event per iteration of the outer loop

Comment: @keltar If I move the rendering functions into the main while loop, make 'float avg' a global and add a avgReady var which I set in the callback and check (and then make 0) in the loop it seems to work. The thing is that it used to work (my original example) before I tried to add some image functionality code (which I removed because it had slowdowns like these I'm facing now) and that had the rendering functions in the callback and the SDL_RenderPresent in main (not that i'm sure it was 100% ok without bugs I hadn't noticed and hadn't popped up).

Comment: @keltar Also if I change bufferSize it breaks the program for values above 9 which didn't happen when my program worked (I updated it by pressing the up and down buttons, closing and reopening the audio device with the new size).

Comment: @JohnGRThess sorry but "it worked before" argument doesn't apply when documentation explicitly says rendering must be done in graphics thread. Thread unsafety doesn't mean it is guaranteed to collapse when misused. As for buffer size - you'll have to define what "breaks" means in that case. If it is a hard crash (e.g. SIGSEGV/access violation) then debugger would provide great help to figure out what happened. At this point, I'm not even sure what you're doing, as callback supposed to fill given buffer, not read from it.

Comment: @JohnGRThess also audio callback's `len` is size in bytes but you're using it as `float` elements count, which is 4 times larger.

Comment: @keltar I normally divide len by 4 which I didn't in the simplifed code I posted, if I divide len by 4 it fixes the buffer len problem so it's ok. I'm reading from the callback because it's an INPUT device, you read the recorded input.

Comment: @JohnGRThess ok, I've never done input. Format `AUDIO_S16` doesn't look like float though, but that might not be very relevant. Is your problem solved?

Comment: @keltar Probably. And even if I open the audio device 'AUDIO_S16' it still opens as float. I should add a check for the opened format.

Answer (score 0):

Don't try to do SDL_Renderer operations in a different thread like the one the audio callback is typically called from.  As @keltar pointed out this is [prohibited by SDL](https://hg.libsdl.org/SDL/file/3c4a4b1077cd/include/SDL_render.h#l44):

> These functions must be called from the main thread.

Instead, bundle up the audio samples via your favorite method for rendering on the main thread (sorry for the C++, not much of a C guy re: threading primitives):

```
#include <SDL.h>
#include <vector>
#include <atomic>
#include <iostream>

// triple-buffering logic stol^H^H^H^Hborrowed from:
// https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49352853
std::vector< float >* g_ProducerBuffer;
std::vector< float >* g_ConsumerBuffer;
std::atomic< std::vector< float >* > g_CurrentBuffer;
void audioInCallback( void* userdata, Uint8* stream, int len )
{
    const float* floatStream = reinterpret_cast< float* >( stream );

    for( auto& sample : *g_ProducerBuffer )
    {
        sample = *floatStream;
        floatStream++;
    }

    // post new buffer
    g_ProducerBuffer = g_CurrentBuffer.exchange( g_ProducerBuffer );
}

int main( int argc, char** argv )
{
    SDL_Init( SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING );
    SDL_SetHint( SDL_HINT_RENDER_VSYNC, "1" );
    //SDL_SetHint( SDL_HINT_RENDER_DRIVER, "software" );
    Uint32 flags = SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN;
    SDL_Window* window = nullptr;
    SDL_Renderer* renderer = nullptr;
    SDL_CreateWindowAndRenderer( 1024, 768, flags, &window, &renderer );

    // dump device names
    int count = SDL_GetNumAudioDevices( 1 );
    for( int i = 0; i < count; i++ )
    {
        std::cout << i << ": " << SDL_GetAudioDeviceName( i, 1 ) << '\n';
    }

    SDL_AudioSpec spec = { 0 };
    spec.freq = 44100;
    spec.format = AUDIO_F32LSB;
    spec.channels = 1;
    spec.samples = 1024;
    spec.callback = audioInCallback;

    const unsigned int deviceIndex = 0;
    const std::string deviceName = SDL_GetAudioDeviceName( deviceIndex, 1 );
    SDL_AudioDeviceID dev = SDL_OpenAudioDevice( deviceName.c_str(), 1, &spec, nullptr, 0 );

    // set up audio buffers
    std::vector< float > buffers[ 3 ];
    buffers[ 0 ].resize( spec.samples );
    buffers[ 1 ].resize( spec.samples );
    buffers[ 2 ].resize( spec.samples );
    g_ProducerBuffer = &buffers[ 0 ];
    g_ConsumerBuffer = &buffers[ 1 ];
    g_CurrentBuffer = &buffers[ 2 ];

    // start audio capture
    SDL_PauseAudioDevice( dev, 0 );

    bool running = true;
    while( running )
    {
        SDL_Event ev;
        while( running && SDL_PollEvent( &ev ) )
        {
            if( SDL_QUIT == ev.type ||
                SDL_KEYDOWN == ev.type && SDL_SCANCODE_ESCAPE == ev.key.keysym.scancode )
            {
                running = false;
            }
        }

        SDL_SetRenderDrawColor( renderer, 0, 0, 0, 255 );
        SDL_RenderClear( renderer );

        // grab latest audio buffer
        // (this *seems* to work on my system but I'm not 100% sure it's correct)
        while( !g_CurrentBuffer.compare_exchange_weak( g_ConsumerBuffer, g_ConsumerBuffer ) );

        // draw audio sample waveform
        std::vector< SDL_Point > points( g_ConsumerBuffer->size() );
        for( size_t i = 0; i < g_ConsumerBuffer->size(); ++i )
        {
            const int x = static_cast< int >( i );
            const int y = static_cast< int >( (*g_ConsumerBuffer)[ i ] * 200 + 768 / 2 );
            points[ i ] = SDL_Point{ x, y };
        }
        SDL_SetRenderDrawColor( renderer, 255, 255, 255, 255 );
        SDL_RenderDrawLines( renderer, points.data(), points.size() );

        SDL_RenderPresent( renderer );
    }

    SDL_CloseAudioDevice( dev );
    SDL_DestroyRenderer( renderer );
    SDL_DestroyWindow( window );
    SDL_Quit();
    return 0;
}
```